# Wait for another ANT build/task to finish

Tags: ant, concurrency, semaphore, wait, flexunit

I would like to make ANT process wait for another build or task to finish.

The situation is: I execute a few ANT builds simultaneously. In these builds there are  tasks to test the apps. Unfortunately, only one flexunit task can be run at the same time, because it uses net socket to communicate with the AIR app.

The build process should wait for the end of the  tasks from other build processes before starting its  task.

How to achieve that?

Thank you for any hints,

Rafal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the <waitfor> task with your choice of synchronization.
I always use an "IGotTheResourceSoYouCantHaveIt" file that gets created after <waitfor> and deleted when I'm done with it.

Details:

- delete the file in some higher-level "clean" so that if a build aborts it gets deleted eventually.
- there's a small race condition between the <waitfor> and creating the file.  In my use, it's not worth worrying about.

Comment: I followed that way, but instead of higher-level clean I used <trycatch> task for deleting lock file in <finally>. Thanks.

Comment: @rafalfy , consider that there are a lot of big-picture failure modes that will blow you out of <ant> altogether, without going through <finally>.  For instance, if a test hangs for some reason, eventually the process will probably get killed off, one way or another.  This may not be a concern - I'm just sayin'.